# How to make WebRTC works between Host and a service in the docker compose network?

Tags: javascript, docker-compose, webrtc

Here is a diagram explaining the issue I am facing and trying to solve.

This prevents my browser to peer connect, through webRTC,  to a service running in a docker container which belongs to the docker-compose default network.

[image]

Here is what I tried so far with no success:

- Using **STUN** and a **TURN** servers
- Using the extra_hosts option in docker compose for both containers with the following value: **host.docker.internal:host-gateway**

So my question is: why the iceConnection transitions from *checking* to *disconnected* states, and more importantly, how to solve this?

**Note:**
My assumption is that the WebRTCPeerconnection from the code running in the web browser fails to connect to the socket opened by the service running in the container because Host and Docker Compose project are not in the same network. I would have thought that the TURN middleman would solve this though, which is not the case apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had actually nothing to do with Docker.

Code running in Browser was sending the wrong RTC offer payload to the destination service.